# Forcing an LSUIElement "Accessory" application to the front

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

I have an `LSUIElement` application that needs to keep it's status as an `LSUIElement` (it cannot have a dock icon) this application is launched and handled by a plugin.

When I change the app so it is a "Regular" app (without `LSUIElement`), `[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES]` works perfectly. However when I make it an `LSUIElement` it shows the window, but the window is stuck behind safari (where the plugin is running) but on top of everything else. I am calling `-[NSWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];` but that doesn't make any difference.

To be clear the "plugin" side is irrelevant as the plugin and application are two separate processes. The plugin sends an event (over a mach port) to the application which calls some code to open the window and bring it to focus. The problem is the code to bring it to focus only works when it's not an `LSUIElement` application.

I've exhaustively searched for an existing call to make this work, I'm open to suggestions on how to fake a mouse click, or even run some applescript to make this work, maybe there's an undocumented method of doing this.

The Apple docs for `LSUIElement` state "The application does not appear in the Dock and does not have a menu bar, but it may be activated programmatically" but I cannot find the magic that enables this.

Comment: pzich in freenode #macdev suggested [NSWindow setLevel:]; setting that to NSMainMenuWindowLevel brings it up in front of safari, however the window is still not key.

Comment: I don't understand this question. `[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES]` is how you should bring your app forward. It should not be causing your app to "remove the LSUIElement" and show a dock icon. Are you actually seeing a dock icon?

Comment: Kurt, just phrased badly. It is now edited for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to activate your app first:

```
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

and then make your window become key window:

```
[NSWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

This works in my project.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach works for me in an app with "LSUIElement" set to "1", even if the entire application is using Cocoa:

```
ProcessSerialNumber psn;
if (noErr == GetCurrentProcess(&psn))
{
    (OSStatus)SetFrontProcess(&psn);
}
```

(This is part of the Carbon API.)

Comment: Tried this to be able to bring up my accessory windows when a different host app moves to fullscreen mode - didn't seem to work.